# Image processing - I need to find the 4 corners of any quadrilater

Tags: java, image-processing

I need to apply the cvWarpPerspective in my images to transform

- this: [ROI original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIL6s.png)
- into this: [Image Warping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaE0L.png)

But to do this I need to pass the corners of the ROIs as parameter, I can't do it manually because I have 306 images and it will cost much time.

I have already tried Harris Corner detector, Susan, and several imagej plugins, but every algorithm I have tried, does not only detect the corners, but more points while I just need the corners. (If I pass more points as parameters, the final image becomes distorted)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your changes to get a helpful answer would be higher if you would formulate a more concrete question. For example you could pick the most promising approach you tried, post some short code examples and state which part of the result is unsatisfying.

Additionally, please read your post again and check your spelling.

Comment: I do not know how to be more specific about the problem : I have a quadrilater and I need to find the 4 corners. The title say "JAVA" so the only requirement is that the answer is in java.
If you want to know more about the methods that I use, here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection , but like I said , they do not work as expected, and i don't have more ideas.
About my English : Sorry, it's not my first language, but english support is better.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea to use Harris corner detector was a good one but in order to get only the corners you need to do some pre processing.

1. Threshold the image and get only the values that are bigger than 0. opencv threshold function.
   [image]
2. Find the two connected components. opencv findContours
3. Find the convex hull of each component. opencv convexhull
4. Fill in the convex hull. opencv fillPoly

[image]

5. Run Harris corner detector. opencv feature detector harris

[image]

6. Do max suppression. For each corner look at his neighborhood if he is the max corner insert one in the new corner image else put zero.

[image]

7. Take the eight most prominent corners. The 4 x corrdinate left one are the left  qaudrilater and the 4 right ones are the right quadrilater

Not Java code but a python implementation hope it will help enough:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Params
neigbrhoodSize = 5

# Read img
img = cv2.imread('AIL6s.png')
img = img[:,:,0]

# Threshold
Ithresh = img
Ithresh[img > 0] = 1

# Find contour
fillImage = np.zeros(Ithresh.shape)
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Ithresh.astype(np.uint8),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )
hulls = []
for contour in contours:

    # Find convex hull for each area
    hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)
    hulls.append(hull)

# Fill the convex area
cv2.fillPoly(fillImage, hulls, 255)

# Run corner detection
corners = cv2.cornerHarris(fillImage.astype(np.uint8), 3, 3, 0.05)

# Run max suppression
maxCorners = corners.flatten().argsort()[-50:][::-1]
maxCornersYX = np.unravel_index(maxCorners,corners.shape)
cornersMaxSupression = np.zeros_like(corners)
for i in range(len(maxCorners)):

    # Look at the neighborhood of the point. If it is the max value insert 1 to cornersMaxSupression else insert 0
    pointX = maxCornersYX[1][i]
    pointY = maxCornersYX[0][i]
    maxArea = np.max(corners[pointY-neigbrhoodSize:pointY+neigbrhoodSize,pointX-neigbrhoodSize:pointX+neigbrhoodSize])
    currentMax = np.max(cornersMaxSupression[pointY-neigbrhoodSize:pointY+neigbrhoodSize,pointX-neigbrhoodSize:pointX+neigbrhoodSize])
    if maxArea==corners[pointY, pointX] and currentMax==0:
        cornersMaxSupression[pointY, pointX] = 1

# Take the eight max values of cornersMaxSupression
eightMaxCorners = corners.flatten().argsort()[-8:][::-1]
eightMaxCornersYX = np.unravel_index(eightMaxCorners,corners.shape)

# Divide the image to the two small images
fillImage[:,1:fillImage.shape[1]/2] = fillImage[:,1:fillImage.shape[1]/2]*2
```

Comment: I think it will help. Thanks, i will give a feedback soon.

Comment: Can you post your code? What params you use in Harris method?

Comment: I wrote it using opencv for python and not JAVA. I can still post the code if you want.

Comment: It would be great.

Comment: @Amitay Nachmani , thanks for the great explanation I tried your code and it worked great, but in my case I need to do the same thing that your code does but on colored images. I tried to use GRAYSCALE before doing all the work ! but the output is always black. Do you know how to work around that ?

Comment: The code assume that the parts you need to find the corner for are already segmented from the image (i.e have a value grater than zero for foreground and 0 for background). If you have a colored image you will need to find a way to segment out the areas before applying the code above.

Comment: I managed to get the end result as yours, now i can't seem to use the last coordinates to crop my image. Since I need only 4 coordinates not like this example I changed it a little bit to give me the four max corners.
For example : this is the output of the MaxCornersYX : 
> (array([57, 57, 58, 58]), array([869, 868, 869, 868]))

how could I use them to crop my original image ?

Comment: it looks that the max suppression stage didn't work right because you get four points which are one next to the other as your corner. You need to fix this