How to form boxes from nearly touching lines
I want to detect corners from a image with boxes, although i created the chessboard edge lines with the EDlines algorithm. Now, I have some problems to join them to create perfect boxes. Could you help me maybe?
ed_anti=cvX.createEdgeDrawing()
            ed_anti.detectEdges(binarized)
            edges_anti=ed_anti.getEdgeImage(None)
            segments_anti=ed_anti.getSegments()#gets the segments of the edges
            gradiant_anti=ed_anti.getGradientImage(None)#detects the gradient of the edges
            ed_lines_anti=ed_anti.detectLines(None)#detects the lines

 if ed_lines_anti is not None: 
            lines_anti = np.uint16(np.around(ed_lines_anti))
            for i in range(len(ed_lines_anti)):
                cv.line(anti_black_image, (lines_anti[i][0][0], lines_anti[i][0][1]), (lines_anti[i][0][2], lines_anti[i][0][3]), (250, 0, 250), 1, cv.LINE_AA)



are you trying to reinvent the extraction of saddle points from a picture of a checkerboard? that has been a common task in computer vision for decades. you should not try to reinvent the wheel before you've learned about the most successful approaches in the literature. -- [mre] required. what's cvX? -- note to others: user's previous questions provide context.

@norb. Can you post original image?

You could try to detect the corners in the original image and connect the closest line-segment ends to the corners.

@toyotaSupra i added the original image, now

Do watershed on your original image.

@fmw42 it's not working. the borders of the image are only highlighted

Show your code for the watershed process after thresholding on either black or white.

@fmw42 i used the code from the documentation on opencv

Did you adjust the morphology arguments and thresholds to suit your image?  Please show your code and the intermediate images.

Did you do the watershed on the checkerboard image or your purple edge image? It should be from the checkerboard, not the edge image.

@norb  Did you see my solution below?

@fmw42 i have seen and am very grateful for your help, but is there a way to minimize the uneven/not straight lines in the contours image, not using erode/dilate on the binarized image, else I will use the edline algorithm, because it does a great job.  You are diverging from the original question, it's not of topic for me, although I tried already a lot and I would be very thankful, if you could help me with connecting these lines in an easy manner.

@norb Why do you need "perfect" boxes?  If you need them, then one way is to draw each box separately and use cv2.approxPolyDP to get the four corner. Another is again for each box to get HoughLines intersections.  I used that approach in my Imagemagick script, quadcorners1. Another way, is to compute the curvature at each pixel (with skip factor) of a box from the contour points and find the maximum curvature. I did that in my script, quadcorners2.  You can find those at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick

@norb See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677434/image-processing-i-need-to-find-the-4-corners-of-any-quadrilater

follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78617152/calibration-or-rectification-is-not-working-properly

Here is one approach in Python/OpenCV to get your boxes.
 - Read the image
 - Convert to grayscale
 - Threshold and invert (to find the original black boxes)
 - Pad with white all around
 - Floodfill with black to turn the white corners to black.
 - Crop the padding away
 - Apply close morphology to fill in black specks
 - Apply erode morphology to separate the cells
 - Get external contours for the cells
 - Draw red contours on a black image
 - Draw red contours on a copy of the input
 - Save the results

Input:

import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('checkerboard.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# add white border and floodfill the border to black
pad = cv2.copyMakeBorder(thresh, 10,10,10,10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(255))
hh, ww = pad.shape
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
floodfill = cv2.floodFill(pad, mask, (0,0), (0), (0), (0), flags=4)[1]
hh, ww = floodfill.shape

# crop padding
crop = floodfill[10:hh-10, 10:ww-10]

# apply morphology to remove small spots and then disconnect cells
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
clean = cv2.morphologyEx(crop, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((9,9), np.uint8)
clean = cv2.morphologyEx(clean, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

# get contours
cntr_img = np.zeros_like(clean)
cntr_img = cv2.merge([cntr_img,cntr_img,cntr_img])
cntr_img2 = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(clean, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 10:
        cv2.drawContours(cntr_img, [cntr], -1, (0,0,255), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(cntr_img2, [cntr], -1, (0,0,255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('checkerboard_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('checkerboard_floodfill.jpg', floodfill)
cv2.imwrite('checkerboard_crop.jpg', crop)
cv2.imwrite('checkerboard_contours.jpg', cntr_img)
cv2.imwrite('checkerboard_contours2.jpg', cntr_img2)
   
# show the results
cv2.imshow('threshold', thresh)
cv2.imshow('floodfill', floodfill)
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.imshow('clean', clean)
cv2.imshow('cntr_img', cntr_img)
cv2.imshow('cntr_img2', cntr_img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Threshold and inverted image:

Floodfilled image:

Cropped image (crop to remove added padding):

Contours on black background:

Contours on copy of input:

